# SQLite - Combining Rows into New Columns

Tags: python, sql, sqlite

I am attempting to create a chatbot in Python 3.9 using my own text messages, but am having trouble formatting my data correctly.

I have a table of text messages that looks like this:

| row_id | Type | Date | Text |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Incoming | 2020-08-10 08:09:18 | Hi |
| 2 | Outgoing | 2020-08-10 08:11:04 | Hello |
| 3 | Incoming | 2020-08-10 08:11:12 | For tomorrow |
| 4 | Incoming | 2020-08-10 08:11:20 | Are we still on for dinner? |
| 5 | Outgoing | 2020-08-10 08:11:31 | Let me check. |
| 6 | Outgoing | 2020-08-10 08:11:43 | Yes |
| 7 | Incoming | 2020-08-10 08:11:45 | Great! |

What I need to do is combine all the Incoming Texts between the last and next Outgoing, and all the Outgoing Texts between the last and next Incoming into a column.

For example, the above table should look like this:

| Incoming | Outgoing |
| --- | --- |
| Hi | Hello |
| For Tomorrow Are we still on for dinner? | Let me check. Yes |
| Great |  |

The conversation is over 17,000 records long.
I am running it in Python 3.9 using sqlite3.

How would I go about completing this task?

Comment: hint: have a look at analytical function-> lead()

Comment: what happens when there are multiple outgoing messages related to one incoming and vice-versa? Please include a table showing what you would expect to see.

Comment: @ggordon The sample data given actually already has these edge cases.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a gaps and islands problem.  We can use the difference in row numbers method here combined with string aggregation:

```sql
WITH cte AS (
    SELECT *, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY Date) rn1,
              ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY Type ORDER BY Date) rn2
    FROM yourTable
),
cte2 AS (
    SELECT *, rn1-rn2 AS grp, DENSE_RANK() OVER (PARTITION BY Type ORDER BY rn1-rn2) rnk
    FROM cte
    ORDER BY grp, rnk
)

SELECT
    GROUP_CONCAT(CASE WHEN Type = 'Incoming' THEN TEXT END, ' ') AS Incoming,
    GROUP_CONCAT(CASE WHEN Type = 'Outgoing' THEN TEXT END, ' ') AS Outgoing
FROM cte2
GROUP BY
    rnk
ORDER BY
    rnk;
```

[image: screen capture from demo link below]

### Demo

Answer (score 1):

You can use analytical function and conditional aggregation as follows:

```
Select group_concat(case when type = 'incoming' then text end, ' ') as incoming_msg,
       Group_concat(case when type = 'outgoing' then text end, ' ') as outgoing_msg
  From
(Select t.*,
       Sum(case when type = lg_type then 0 else 1 end) over (order by date) as sm
  From
(Select t.*,
       Lag(type) over (order by date) as lg_type
  From t) t) t
Group by sm
```